# Trying to run a script after maildrop delivers email

Tags: linux, postfix, bash

I'm trying to get maildrop to run a script after it delivers the email in the /var/mail/user folder.

`/etc/postfix/master.cf` contains

```
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop-wrapper -d ${recipient}
```

`/usr/bin/maildrop-wrapper` is a simple bash script that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/maildrop $@
/usr/bin/php -f /home/user/my.php
```

Emails are correctly delivered to `/var/mail/user` and can be read by `mail` but the `my.php` is not executed

I can run `my.php` directly without problems, so I know the problem has to be somewhere in the execution before but I cannot figure it out (I know very little bash scripting though, so it might be obvious to anyone else).

Alternatively, a solution without the wrapper-file would be appreciated as well. I tried placing

```
`/usr/bin/php -f /home/user/my.php`
```

in `/etc/maildroprc` but it didn't work.

Comment: Does your script run with the same username and group as Postfix? Or rather can the script be called by postfix users. Hint: Look if o+x has been set for `/home/user/my.php` or alternative use chown to set script as same userid and group as postfix.

Comment: Chmod is 0755, so it should be . Also tried chown to postfix:postfix but no changes. I also tried running the script again with another user (who is not postfix) and it worked

Comment: Digging around and found this on Courrier-MTA homepage: "The name of the file may not contain any periods". Wondering if `my.php` is an illegal name and therefore not activated maildrop? If my.php is just a shell script written in php, you could rename my.php to something else that doesn't contain a period.